# Local Video Streaming Callback

Tags: python, arduino, live, esp32

So I have ESP32 camera connected on my arduino, and I have configured everything that I can now stream video with the help of that camera on a local address of : http://192.168.43.87/
However, I want to get that live video file imported in my python file, in which I am going to do live detections. How can I import it?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("http://192.168.43.87/stream?") <- This is where it is needed to import

while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()
    hsv_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # Red color
    low_red = np.array([161, 155, 84])
    high_red = np.array([179, 255, 255])
    red_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_frame, low_red, high_red)
    red = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=red_mask)

    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    cv2.imshow("Red", red)


    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

````
import cv
import socket

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(('192.168.1.100', 8000))
connection = client_socket.makefile('wb')

stream_bytes = b' '
while True:
    stream_bytes += self.connection.read(1024)
    first = stream_bytes.find(b'\xff\xd8')
    last = stream_bytes.find(b'\xff\xd9')
    if first != -1 and last != -1:
        jpg = stream_bytes[first:last + 2]
        stream_bytes = stream_bytes[last + 2:]
        image = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(jpg, dtype=np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        cv2.imshow('image', image)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
           break`import numpy as np
import cv
import socket

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(('192.168.1.100', 8000))
connection = client_socket.makefile('wb')

stream_bytes = b' '
while True:
    stream_bytes += self.connection.read(1024)
    first = stream_bytes.find(b'\xff\xd8')
    last = stream_bytes.find(b'\xff\xd9')
    if first != -1 and last != -1:
        jpg = stream_bytes[first:last + 2]
        stream_bytes = stream_bytes[last + 2:]
        image = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(jpg, dtype=np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        cv2.imshow('image', image)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
           break```
````